# How add one to a list element?

Tags: python

I have an empty `list` called mylist which looks like

```
[None,None,None,None,None,None,None]
```

I have a for loop which will add one to each element each time its past over.

I am trying to add 1 to an element using:

```
mylist[i] = mylist[i]+1
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The number of times the list is iterated over changes so ican't just add one to all elements.

The code I'm using is:

```
for j in range(0,bucketSize):
    for i in range (0,minibuckets):
        list[i] = list[i]+1
```

Comment: Doesn't that `for` loop effectively just equate to: `mylist[:miniBuckets] = [el or 0 + bucketSize for el in mylist[:miniBuckets]]`? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: You can use `False` instead of `None`: `False + 1` -> `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should initialise your list to be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, because you cannot do `None + 1`. It really doesn't make sense to try to add 1 to something that is effectively nothing. `None` is a very different concept than 0.

For example:

```
mylist = [0] * 7
# or
mylist = [0 for i in range(7)]
```

Alternatively you can check for `None` in your inner for-loop:

```
if mylist[i] is None:
    mylist[i] = 1
else:
    mylist[i] += 1
```

Or the same check in one line:

```
mylist[i] = mylist[i] + 1 is mylist[i] is not None else 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`None` is very different from `0`.  In effect it is no value at all.

The simple solution to this is simply check for `None` in your loop.

```
for j in range(0,bucketSize):
    for i in range (0,minibuckets):
        if list[i] is None:
            list[i] = 1
        else:
            list[i] = list[i]+1
```

Alternatively initialize your list to `0` or replace `None` with `0` before starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you can not change `None` to `0`:

```
mylist[i] = mylist[i]+1 if mylist[i] else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
my_list = [None,None,None,None,None,None,None]

print(['1' if v is None else v for v in my_list])
```

Outputs:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```